# hazelcast 3.6 properly shutting down node

Tags: hazelcast

I try to figure out why I am loosing data when I take one node down. I have development cluster with 2 nodes running hazelcast 3.6 application. HZ app is configured to have 271 partition and I write 271 unique keys to cluster via remote client. I verified that data is properly distributed between two nodes and stored and back up on other node.

after a while I stop writing to cluster I only read from it, then I am shutting down one of the nodes from this cluster. before that I call shutdown method on the instance, I then check if cluster is safe.

```
Hazelcast.shutdownAll();
for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    log.info("Verifying whether it is safe to close this instance");
    boolean isSafe = getResultsForAllInstances(hzi -> hzi
            .getPartitionService()
            .forceLocalMemberToBeSafe(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
    if (isSafe) {
        log.info("Verifying whether cluster is safe.");
        isSafe = getResultsForAllInstances(hzi -> hzi
                .getPartitionService()
                .isClusterSafe());
        if (isSafe) {
            break;
        }
    }

    Uninterruptibles.sleepUninterruptibly(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

private boolean getResultsForAllInstances(Function<HazelcastInstance, Boolean> hazelcastInstanceBooleanFunction) {
    return getAllHazelcastInstances().stream()
            .map(hazelcastInstanceBooleanFunction)
            .reduce(true, (old, next) -> old && next);
}
```

unfortunately other node is logging partition lost and I lose data.

[here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hazelcast/oMR65_kqlbM) is a question I've asked on google group but no one replied for this, so I still don't know is this a general problem with 3.6 or I am doing something stupid.

I've also found [bug](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hazelcast/FHVGPjrLEvs) reports for scenarios when nodes were terminated instantly but in my case I try to [shutdown node gracefully](https://hazelcast.org/deployment-operations-guide/#topology-changes-nodes-joining-and-leaving) and it has time to communicate back to other node. So what am I missing here :]

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is the replication level of your data? If you want your data to be up and running despite loosing nodes you need to have backups.
Example.

```
<hazelcast>
  <map name="default">
    <backup-count>1</backup-count>
  </map>
</hazelcast>
```

The default backup is one. That means that every entity is only stored once therefore exists in only one node. So if the aforementioned node fails you lose all its data. Hope this helps :)

Comment: "I verified that data is properly distributed between two nodes and stored and back up on other node." so my data is backing up on other node.

Comment: I maybe should add that I am using my own service, based on SPI.

Comment: anyway I can see that data is replicating between nodes in cluster

Comment: What about your read from backup property? Do you have that on? Also, when the node shuts down does the other node have the backups (see that from debugging mode not by asking the node for data).

Comment: because I am writing my own service using SPI I haven't added that option yet ;]. 
Ok I will look at debug mode. but I am pretty sure that other nodes have data. AND ... it turns out that the biggest issue is that client throws timeout exceptions when I shutdown node. probably this is the reason why I see "data loss" - my client's logic is such, when there is no response/error/etc/ decision is to write. I ve already change that, but I didn't expect client to throw timeout ...

Comment: I would expect that if I call instance.shutdown() it will communicate with other nodes and clients about the fact, switch to OUT_OF_SERVICE mode, handle all incoming request, awaits for other node to take ownership and then shuts down. 
I understand it is not that easy :D

Comment: Reveka, by "debugging mode" you mean just to change default log level for hazelcast, right? if yes I ve already done that for my service and you can look at it https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hazelcast/oMR65_kqlbM

Comment: hmmm...by debugging I meant from your IDE but since you cannot reproduce the bug locally that will not help. Have you tried adding a third node? Does the data distribute? And if you close this node what portion of the data will be lost. I am just throwing debugging ideas to minimize the variables because now I seriously don't have any clue why a cluster would behave like that.

Comment: so giving this second though I am convinced that data are stored and backup properly. Maybe I thought I lost them because PartitionLostListener was logging information about that. So maybe this is the only reason I was suspicious AND confused. There is no much in documentation about PLL.

Comment: So what you mean is that you never had a problem when you asked for data? Your data was there all along?

Comment: I think so, so I don't understand why PartitionLost events are published.

Comment: Maybe you should update your question and mark it as resolved. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like data was not lost but I got lots of connection-lost errors on client side just after shutting down one of nodes - and business logic that handled such exceptions was incorrect. 
this is fair as shutdown is not communicating anything back to client.

the other false lead were partition-lost events I got on the other node. I still don't understand this mechanism and I wish there was more explanation in HZ's documentation.

@Reveka thanks for being patient! :]